# Can I select unselectable text in Safari?

Tags: safari, text, web-browser, websites

I am trying to copy and paste the dimensions of [this box](https://store.usps.com/store/product/shipping-supplies/priority-mail-flat-rate-medium-box-1-P_O_FRB1) on the USPS website in Safari.

For some mysterious reason, I am unable to do so.

**Is there a way to select this text without changing browsers?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1: Use a third-party tool or take a screenshot

I really like [TextSniper](https://textsniper.app/) (paid, $7.99) for this, and it works on any app and even inside pictures or paused videos.

It provides a shortcut (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> by default) to select a region in the screen and uses OCR to copy the selected text to the clipboard.

It's not perfect but is accurate in 90% of cases in my experience. A little cleanup is required for the other 10%, but it's still a time-saver even then.

As suggested by @Alper, if you don't want to use a paid third-party tool, you can instead take a screenshot with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, open the screenshot with Preview, and select the text there using the [Live Text](https://support.apple.com/en-bh/guide/preview/prvw625a5b2c/mac) feature available in recent macOS versions.

---

#### Option 2: Use the Web Inspector

If you don't want to use third-party software, you're in luck, since the text you want to copy is not part of a picture, the web developer just disabled selection. Nothing that can't be worked around, but it'll require looking under the hood a little bit.

First, you will need to enable developer mode by turning on **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Advanced** > **Show Develop menu in the menu bar**.

Now when you right-click on any portion of any web page, a new option will appear in the context menu called **Inspect Element**. Right-click on the un-selectable text and click on **Inspect Element**.

A web developer tools panel will appear. There are many parts to it, but all you need for this is the big panel on the left with a hierarchy of items that look like `<div class=...`, `<span class=...` and so on. The underlying HTML element you right-clicked on will be selected and highlighted in blue. It looks like this:

```html
<span class="sku-id" id="prodDisplaySkuSize">11-1/4"(L) x 8-3/4"(W) x 6"(H)</span>
```

This is called an HTML element. It has three parts: the beginning tag (`<span class="sku-id" id="prodDisplaySkuSize">`), the content (`11-1/4"(L) x 8-3/4"(W) x 6"(H)`), and the ending tag (`</span>`).

Right-click on the content and click on Copy > Text. This will copy the following to the clipboard:

```
                    11-1/4"(L) x 8-3/4"(W) x 6"(H)
```

You may need to clean up the leading whitespace depending on how you want to use this.

---

#### Option 3: Re-enable text selection

Another option is to override the developer's decision and re-enable text selection on the web page. To do this, you'll need to enable developer mode as above by turning on **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Advanced** > **Show Develop menu in menu bar**.

Now open the Console by selecting **Develop** > **Show JavaScript Console** or by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Paste the following code into the console and press Enter:

```js
var style = document.createElement('style'); style.textContent = '* { -webkit-user-select: initial !important; }'; document.body.appendChild(style)
```

You can now close the console using the `X` button at the top-left if you want.

Now you can select and copy any text on the web page as usual. You'll need to open the console and enter the above code again if you reload or reopen the page.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is a direct and easy way applicable to all such web sites so that one does not have to use a browser other than Safari in such cases.

I think some of the easiest ways in Safari are to either save the web page in Page Source format (File->Save As), save it as a PDF file (File->Export as PDF...), or take a screenshot (press Command+Shift+3 while the web page is open) in order to use the [Live Text feature](https://support.apple.com/en-bh/guide/preview/prvw625a5b2c/mac) in Preview.

After saving the web page in either of these formats, open the saved file, find the part you are trying to select, select it with your mouse, and press Command+C to copy it. Depending on the web site, either of these three methods may or may not work which means you may have to try one after another until you get a satisfactory result.

As long as the text to be selected is not part of a picture or a video, I think the surest way is to use the Developer tools in Safari but this method is less straightforward than the three already mentioned.

To use the Developer tools, if not already enabled, you need to enable the Develop menu in Safari by getting into Safari->Settings, clicking Advanced, and then selecting “Show Develop menu in menu bar”. Once enabled, right click on the text you wish to copy, select "Inspect Element", right click on the highlighted part of the HTML code that will appear, select Copy and then choose Text or HTML. I am pasting below the screenshot of an example for this last method.

[image]

Comment: @theonlygusti It doesn't look like you tried your solution, you would have realized it doesn't apply to the webpage linked in the original question. Visit the link provided in the original question and see for yourself that is it not applicable.

Comment: In the Elements tab of the Inspect Element window (screenshotted in this answer), you can also double-click in the text you want to select it all. Then ⌘C does exactly what right-click > Copy > Text would have done, and you can even use your arrow keys/mouse pointer now to select less than all of the text if you want to copy only a part of the unselectable text.

Comment: @MicroMachine my previous comment is better phrased as the new comment I've posted that clarifies the context of the operation (you have to use Inspect Element first). Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way because it is not text—it is pixels in an image.  When I've been faced with something like that, I copy the image, crop it down to just the text in [GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/), increase the contrast with GraphicConverter, then convert to text with [Cisdem OCR](https://www.cisdem.com/pdf-converter-ocr-mac.html).

But I'd never go through all that for something so small.  I'd just type it out:

```
6"  8¾"  11¼"
```

By the way, you **can** copy what I just typed.  :-)

EDIT: After writing that, I noticed that the same dimensions do appear as text to the right of the image.  I was able to copy and paste that as follows: on menu, View→Show Reader, then in the simplified Reader view, the text can be selected and copied.